# Python program that simulates a game of dice with both players controlled by the computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, probability, dice

The program should randomly choose which player goes first. It
should keep a total score for each player, and alternate turns between
the computer players until one player ends its turn with a score of
100 or higher.

Here is how I tried to solve the problem:

```
import random
print("Well, hello there")
def roll_the_dice():
    dice_value = random.randint(1,6)
    return dice_value
def roll_AI(player):
    point = 0
   checker = 1
   while (checker==1):
        dice_value = roll_the_dice()
        print("- rolled a :" , dice_value)
        if dice_value==1:
            print("Pigged out, mate!")
            point=0
            checker=0
        else:
            point += dice_value
            print("Your total be: ",point)
    print("Turns over, mate!")
    return point
playerOne = 0 #Score of P1
playerTwo = 0 #Score of P2
while (playerOne<100 and playerTwo<100):
    whos_turn = random.randint(1,2)
    if (whos_turn==1):
        print("Initial point of both of these bots be 0.")
        dice_value = roll_AI(1)
        playerOne+=dice_value
        print("Now, player one score: ",playerOne)
    else:
        dice_value = roll_AI(2)
        playerTwo += dice_value
        print("Now, player two score: ",playerTwo)
    print("GAMES OVER!")
    print("Player One:",playerOne)
    print("Player Two:",playerTwo)
if playerOne>playerTwo:
    print("Player one wins!")
elif playerTwo>playerOne:
    print("Player two wins!")
else:
    print("ITS A DRAW!.")
```

Here is a sample output of what the program should run:

```
Player One’s score: 0
Player Two’s score: 0
It’s Player One’s turn
- rolled a 1
Pigged out!
Total turn score = 0
Player One’s score: 0
Player Two’s score: 0
It’s Player Two’s turn
- rolled a 6
- rolled a 2
...
Player One’s score: 85
Player Two’s score: 88
It’s Player One’s turn
- rolled a 2
- rolled a 6
- rolled a 2
- rolled a 4
- rolled a 3
Total turn score = 17
Final score: 102 vs 88
Player One wins!
```

My program is running an infinite while loop. Can someone guide me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try using a debugger and single-stepping through the code. iPython has a nice interactive debugger with good auto-completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried sticking to your format best I could, used a `while True` loop in combination with a `for` loop, if either player hit 100 on their turn the `for` loop breaks to stop the next player from getting a turn, followed by the `while` loop breaking

```
import random

players = ['player_one', 'vash']
scores = {'player_one': 0, 'vash': 0}
print('Well, hello there')
random.shuffle(players)

while True:
    for i in players:
        turn_score = 0  
        while turn_score <= 20:
            roll = random.randint(1,6)
            if roll == 1:
                turn_score = 0
                scores[i] += 0
                print('\n{} rolled a {}. Pigged out!'.format(i, roll))
                break
            else:
                turn_score += roll
                print('\n{} rolled a {}.'.format(i, roll))
        scores[i] += turn_score
        print('Turn score: {}'.format(turn_score))
        print('{} score: {} {} score: {}'.format(players[0], scores[players[0]], players[1], scores[players[1]]))
        if scores[i] > 100:
            break
    if scores[i] > 100:
        break

winner = [i for i in scores if scores[i] == max(scores.values())]
print('{} is the winner!'.format(*winner))
```

> ```
> Well, hello there
>
> vash rolled a 2.
>
> vash rolled a 1. Pigged out!
> Turn score: 0
> vash score: 0 player_one score: 0
>
> player_one rolled a 5.
>
> player_one rolled a 4.
>
> player_one rolled a 5.
>
> player_one rolled a 6.
>
> player_one rolled a 6.
> Turn score: 26
> vash score: 0 player_one score: 26
>
> ....
>
> vash score: 89 player_one score: 94
>
> vash rolled a 3.
>
> vash rolled a 4.
>
> vash rolled a 4.
>
> vash rolled a 4.
>
> vash rolled a 3.
>
> vash rolled a 6.
> Turn score: 24
> vash score: 113 player_one score: 94
> vash is the winner!
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`roll_AI(player)` only terminates `if dice_value==1` but then sets `point=0` and returns `0`. So no points can add up towards 100

Comment: So I should add a break statement instead? I want the looping to stop once a 1 is rolled and continue the next players turn.

Comment: @ggezpython3 Using `break` may look prettier but that isn't the problem. Why do you set `point=0` in the `if dice_value==1:` block?

Comment: To reset it if a 1 rolls up I guess